# How to return Integer.parseInt back to string (in for loop)

Tags: loops, for-loop

this is the code i try to fix.

```
while (check){
                System.out.print("What you want to buy? (choose by #, or by Brand, or by ID): ");
                String choice = scan.next();

                for (int i = 0; i <= productList.getListOfProducts().size(); i++) {

                    if (choice.equals(productList.getListOfProducts().get(i).getBrand())
                    || choice.equals(productList.getListOfProducts().get(i).getProductSerialNumber())
                    || Integer.parseInt(choice) == i){
                    ...}
                        break;
                    }
```

It works well if I input from keyboard the numeric chars, or the
similar correct value which is equal to productList.getListOfProducts().get(0).getBrand() or productList.getListOfProducts().get(0).getProductSerialNumber(). BUT if the loop gets to the second step it gives me this mistake:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AA00004"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:54)

As I understand when the checking in IF reaches this part ( Integer.parseInt(choice) == i) Choice becomes
int for the rest of the loop. What can i do to return it to String format again for every new step. Thank you!

Comment: Integer.parseInt(choice) - It may throw error if choice contains "AA00004" as it is alphanumeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this, is because `AA000004` isn't a valid Integer, because hexadecimal representations are not considered Integers. I'd suggest catching the NumberFormatException if it is not a valid Integer.

If you know that input might be a hexadecimal value (or match any other regular pattern), you could perform a RegEx match (regular expression) to see if it matches a certain pattern. Depending on what is more likely, you'd want to see if the given variable `choice` (String) is parsable to an Integer first. If it's not, you might proceed to either give corresponding feedback to the user or check whether the value is hexadecimal (or of any other predictable format) and deduct or convert the variable from String to corresponding data type.

You could use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/IntegerValidator.html#validate%28java.lang.String%29 (Apache Commons IntegerValidator class) to check and return either `null` or the actual Integer value.

Comment: if I will use AA00001 (instead of 4) it gose ok because AA00001 is the 0 position and if statment do not reach the Integer.parseInt(choice) == i) the problem comes ONLY if it gets to Integer.parseInt(choice) == i).
for example if i will take out the /*Integer.parseInt(choice) == i)*/ from the if statement... there will be no problems, but i will not be able to check the numeric input at all.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is expected to throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input variable (`choice` in your case) is invalid. So I am sure if your input is a valid Integer, it works. If it isn't **and** either of your previous conditions does not evaluate to true, it then hits `Integer.parseInt` with a String, which cannot be converted to an Integer value.